# R markdown won't load due to a missing package, 'backports', which also fails to download.

Tags: r, installation, knitr, r-markdown, package

Here I attempt to download an earlier version of 'backports' to deal with the issue. Any ideas where to look or how to approach this issue?

```
> library(devtools)
Warning message:
package ‘devtools’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
> install_version("backports",version="1.1.0")
Trying https://cran.rstudio.com/
Trying http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin
Downloading package from url: https://cran.rstudio.com//src/contrib/Archive/backports/backports_1.1.0.tar.gz
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Timeout was reached
> install.packages("rmarkdown")
 Installing package into ‘H:/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

 There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
           binary source needs_compilation
rmarkdown    1.4    1.8             FALSE

installing the source package ‘rmarkdown’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_1.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2093181 bytes (2.0 MB)
downloaded 2.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'rmarkdown' ...
** package 'rmarkdown' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
there is no package called 'backports'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rmarkdown'
* removing 'H:/R/win-library/3.2/rmarkdown'
* restoring previous 'H:/R/win-library/3.2/rmarkdown'
Warning in install.packages :
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l 
"H:\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\jacarter\AppData\Local\Temp\3\RtmpULt4Do/downloaded_packages/rmarkdown_1.8.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status
```

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\jacarter\AppData\Local\Temp\3\RtmpULt4Do\downloaded_packages’

Comment: what is your R version? I just installed backports without problem using install_version("backports",version="1.1.0")

Comment: from your logs I have the impression that you just experienced a network problem while installing backports, did you tried afterward?

Comment: Hi! Great catch there, my version of R was OLD 3.2.1. Make sure to update, people.